# Reading files with leading zero bash command line

Tags: regex, bash, loops, command-line

For example I have 15 files as fallows:

abc01.txt, abc02.txt, ..., ..., abc09.txt, abc10.txt, abc11.txt, ...    ... abc15.txt

I want to read these files from command line using bash and perform some operation.

```
for i in {1..15}; do COMMAND abc$i.txt; done
```

Above statement only reads files from 10 to 15 because of leading 0 for the first nine files. If I use `[0]` before $ in the above command then it only reads first 9 files. I want to read all files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `bash` 4.0 leading zero [is supported](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashchanges#quoting_expansions_substitutions_and_related) in `{0x..0y}` (zero-padded brace expansion). With it, you can do it like this:

```
for i in {01..15}; do COMMAND "abc$i.txt"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `printf` with zero padded formatting in *process substitution*:

```
while read -r f; do
   echo "processing $f"
done < <(printf "abc%02d.txt\n" {1..15})
```